# 80's two part series about a time travelling human male in a spaceship with puppets who visits Earth

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship

The man in question falls in love with a human on planet Earth, after travelling back in time and ends up being his own father. His crew are all puppets. I believe the second part in the series was cancelled.

Comment: Were they puppets in- or out- of universe?

Comment: This feels like the love child of Farscape and Red Dwarf.

Comment: 80's 2 partner where a time traveller becomes his own father immediately brings to mind 'The flip side of Dominic Hyde' / 'Another flip for Dominic' (he actually becomes his own great grandfather) but he is unaccompanied and there are no puppets of any sort, so not a good match unless this has been seriously mis-remembered or conflated with something else.

Comment: @AdmiralJota With a dash of MST3K thrown in for good measure! And maybe some clangers as well. :D

Comment: What kind of puppets? _Thunderbirds_-style? Or more like Muppets?

Comment: @OrganicMarble puppets/Muppets stayed on the spaceship orbiting the earth.

Comment: @Spencer Kind of fluffy muppet style.

Comment: Aston, @OrganicMarble is asking if the puppets were supposed to be regarded as puppets or people/aliens from the persepective of the story.

Comment: @Spencer Ahh, right I see what you mean, the muppet'y creatures were the crew of the spaceship, so I guess sort of people. Kind of a Captain EO kind of vibe. They were somewhat bumbling fools, mostly breaking more than they repaired. Thanks for trying by the way.

Comment: Reminds me of Predestination, a movie made from a Robert Heinlein story where the same man is every character in the story. He fathers himself, births himself, and grows up to become the terrorist he's been chasing for years after being the cop who was chasing him. But I don't recall any puppets, so this probably isn't it.